# Wix: Upgrading/Uninstalling a product who codes doesn't match

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, uninstallation

Experts,
I have come to this confusing situation:

1. Installed Product ABC Ver 1.0 (normal installation on fresh machine)
2. Installed Product ABC Ver 2.0 *(redesigned totally in WIX from scratch)*, so Product GUID, Upgrade GUID and Version are totally different. Only shares some folders in ProgramData and ProgramFiles.

**Problem:** ABC Ver 2.0 is removing files of ABC Ver 1.0 and uninstalling/upgrading ABC Ver 1.0.

**Question:** What are the possibilities of such Uninstallation/Upgrading of a product whose codes and structure doesn't match.?

I can't find any custom action or any other thing which makes ABC ver 2.0 to recognize ABC ver 1.0 as its previous version.

Any help/suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks a bunch
Farrukh

Answer (score 1):

If the component guids are duplicated across the versions, windows installer will treat them as the same component even if the items contained within them are different. That will be the only way that this can happen. If you want to enable side-by-side installation you will need to ensure that all component guids are different. See the MSDN docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Caveman_dick for good article, and I will read that. But it doesn't seems to be the situation as we generated everything from scratch using Heat.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh... our bad... This was a problem, deep inside our build procedure. One of our VbScript was modifying the msi while injecting a HardCoded upgrade code...

My bad is, I should have look into msi directly instead of looking into environment variables in our build procedure.

:(